# Is there a way to work with PyUSB under Windows (10) without changing drivers?

Tags: libusb, pyusb, libusb-1.0

I tried to run PyUSB under Windows and in a first test simply wanted to read out all my USB devices with usb.core.find(find_all = True). But that failed with backends iibusb0 and libusb1. Meanwhile I read several times that I need to change the driver of the device I want to talk to through PyUSB eg using Zadig.
As I want to use the devices with different programs I can't change drivers.
So my questions are:

- is changing the driver the only way to use PyUSB?
- what other options are there for USB under Python and Windows
- I downloaded USBTreeView and that runs fine - without changing any drivers. How does it do it? (I know its not Python)
  Thanks for any help
  Martin